# Javascript click() is not working on a button

Tags: javascript, dom, click

I have a button that has following HTML structure:

[image: HTML Tree]

When the button is inspected it points to last line:

```
<div class="gw-label"><div class="gw-shortcutKey">E</div>dit Account</div>
```

However, following line is not clicking the button (nor it is returning an error):

```
document.getElementById("AccountFile_Summary-AccountFile_SummaryScreen-EditAccount").children[0].children[1].click()
```

Any suggestions?

I tried followings, but did not work:

```
document.getElementById("AccountFile_Summary-AccountFile_SummaryScreen-EditAccount").click()
document.getElementById("AccountFile_Summary-AccountFile_SummaryScreen-EditAccount").children[0].click()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the following if the button is the only instance of the class 'gw-action--inner'?

```
document.querySelector('.gw-action--inner').click()
```